# Rails : Sessions : Memcached : failover plan with Dalli

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, amazon-web-services, memcached, aws-opsworks

I have a Rails Application running in AWS Opsworks. 
I want to keep session data in memcached rather than a session cookie.

It appears simple to use [Dalli](https://github.com/mperham/dalli) to make this happen.

However, I am concerned about what happens to my application if memcached is not available for session storage.

Is it possible to failover to cookie or tmp file based if memcached is not available?

What is the preferred failover strategy for sessions in Rails?